# Spring boot com Docker e Mysql sem Docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

Tenho uma aplicação java com spring boot e mysql, coloquei a minha aplicação rodando em container docker mas não quero que o mysql fique em docker.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer minha aplicação conectar no mysql que esta instalado no host.

segue meu Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest

RUN mkdir /etc/app  
VOLUME /tmp

COPY app.jar /etc/app
COPY application.properties /etc/app
COPY application-prod.properties /etc/app

ENTRYPOINT [ "java" , "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar" ,"/etc/app/app.jar"]
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível

Comment: Ja trabalhou com docker-composer? Se não, tenta realizar sua conexão através de docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa subir o container da sua aplicação apontando o ip da sua maquina na rede local como host do banco de dados.

OU então você pode subir com o parametro `--net host`